# Converting Pixel Coordinates to spatial coordinates: Python, Ros

Tags: ros, python, camera

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

So currently, i am reading an image from my robot's camera, located on its hand. I want to obtain the set of coordinates of a certain object, from both the camera's perspective and the robot's base perspective, given a certain pixel coordinate from the camera i.e. 340x200 (location of my object on the camera image)

I have been using the equation on the second line from this [link](http://opencv.itseez.com/2.4/modules/calib3d/doc/camera_calibration_and_3d_reconstruction.html#calibratecamera)

But i haven't obtained any good results.(I have inverted the equation,, since i want a set of 3d coordinates from a pair of pixel coordinates and not the opposite as the original equation would give)

So because i didnt get any good result, i tried breaking down the equation. The matrix [R|T] converts the [x,y,z,1] coordinates to the base frame right?? (assuming [R|T] is with respect to the base frame)

So if I wanted the coordinate WRT to the camera's frame, could I just use the equation, without the [R|T] matrix? i.e [u,v,1] = A[X,Y,Z]?

If not, how should i proceed to convert the pixel coordinates to spatial coordinates

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/237391/converting-pixel-coordinates-to-spatial-coordinates:-python,-ros/) by [laurent](https://answers.ros.org/users/27099/laurent/) on ROS Answers with karma: 21 on 2016-06-17

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I didn't really read the details of your question very closely, nor did I look at the link. It seems to me that there are so many different conventions and coordinate systems used for camera geometry it often leads to confusion. If you are using a camera calibrated with [camera_calibration](http://wiki.ros.org/camera_calibration), and the camera information is available as a [CameraInfo](http://docs.ros.org/api/sensor_msgs/html/msg/CameraInfo.html) topic, then I'd recommend using the [image_geometry](http://wiki.ros.org/image_geometry) package. The two packages are specifically designed to work together, and the `image_geometry` package contains a number of useful functions. Check out the [Python API](http://docs.ros.org/api/image_geometry/html/python/) and the [C++ API](http://docs.ros.org/api/image_geometry/html/c++/).

---

Originally posted by [jarvisschultz](https://answers.ros.org/users/1272/jarvisschultz/) with karma: 9031 on 2016-06-17

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [laurent](https://answers.ros.org/users/27099/laurent/) on 2016-06-20**:
I tried using image_geometry, but i get a 'NoneType' object has no attribute '**getitem**' error when using it. Here's what i did

```
self.img_geo = PinholeCameraModel()
(r_x,r_y,r_z) = self.img_geo.projectPixelTo3dRay((359,28))
```

any idea whats going on?

**Comment by [laurent](https://answers.ros.org/users/27099/laurent/) on 2016-06-20**:
I obviously imported the packages beforehand

**Comment by [jarvisschultz](https://answers.ros.org/users/1272/jarvisschultz/) on 2016-06-20**:
You need to read in the camera calibration parameters

```
cam_info = rospy.wait_for_message("/camera1/camera_info", CameraInfo, timeout=None)
img_proc = PinholeCameraModel()
img_proc.fromCameraInfo(cam_info)
n = img_proc.projectPixelTo3dRay((30,30))
```

**Comment by [laurent](https://answers.ros.org/users/27099/laurent/) on 2016-06-20**:
So I added that bit to my code, but it seems that the code stops at rospy.wait_for_message and doesnt compute the rest

**Comment by [laurent](https://answers.ros.org/users/27099/laurent/) on 2016-06-20**:
So I figrued that that cam_info was basically just subscribing to a camera, so i replcaed the wait_for_message with directly subscribing to the camera. and the error that i get says that 'Subscriber' object has no attribute 'K'

**Comment by [jarvisschultz](https://answers.ros.org/users/1272/jarvisschultz/) on 2016-06-20**:
Your first comment indicates, most likely, that you weren't publishing a CameraInfo message on the `/camera1/camera_info` topic. Your second comment indicates that you are passing the created subscriber into the `fromCameraInfo` method. That is not correct.

**Comment by [jarvisschultz](https://answers.ros.org/users/1272/jarvisschultz/) on 2016-06-20**:
The `wait_for_message` function creates a subscriber, waits until the topic is published, and returns a copy of the message that was received. My code doesn't return a subscriber, it returns a CameraInfo message that has been filled out with information from camera calibration.

**Comment by [laurent](https://answers.ros.org/users/27099/laurent/) on 2016-06-20**:
So given that I revert back to `wait_for_message`, how do i publish a CameraInfo message? You can't publish to the camera right, you can only subscribe to it

**Comment by [jarvisschultz](https://answers.ros.org/users/1272/jarvisschultz/) on 2016-06-20**:
Most camera drivers provide functionality to automatically publish this topic based on a calibrated camera yaml file. You should also be able to manually publish this from the command line using rostopic pub.

**Comment by [laurent](https://answers.ros.org/users/27099/laurent/) on 2016-06-20**:
It turns out i was wrongly entering my topic. I managed to get it to work, thank you so much, your help has been immensely useul

**Comment by [jarvisschultz](https://answers.ros.org/users/1272/jarvisschultz/) on 2016-06-20**:
Glad to hear it! Please close your other question, or provide an answer describing how you solved the problem. http://answers.ros.org/question/237563/subscriber-object-has-no-attribute-k-image_geometry-python-ros/

**Comment by [laurent](https://answers.ros.org/users/27099/laurent/) on 2016-06-20**:
I have a quick question. Now that i have that unit vector passing through the center point of my camera, how do i convert that into real 3d coordinates?

**Comment by [jarvisschultz](https://answers.ros.org/users/1272/jarvisschultz/) on 2016-06-21**:
AFAIK you can't do this without another piece of information. E.g. if you know how far away the object is, you can correctly scale the x,y components. Or, if you have vectors pointing to multiple keypoints on an object with known size and orientation.

**Comment by [jarvisschultz](https://answers.ros.org/users/1272/jarvisschultz/) on 2016-06-21**:
Tag tracking systems and checkerboard calibrators get pose estimation by knowing that the black/white corners are all on the same plane and either knowing how big the marker/checkerboard is, or being able to extract that info somehow.